# [Facebook Graph API]: How to get test user access token with specific scope

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

For my Test users the access token I can obtain has always the same scopes:

```
public_profile, basic_info, user_friends
```

I didn't find a way to modify the access token provided by the test users in the interface or via an API call.

Is there a simple way to modify the scope of the access token of a test user?

Comment: how to get test user albums detail please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the password for the test user and login in directly as the test user using the email address provided. You can then use the login button in your application to grant the test user any additional permissions that are required.

As a general guide, you should always test your application with a test user. It can sometimes reveal issues that wouldn't otherwise have been noticed until a real-user experiences it.

Comment: As I am working on just the server side, and the Facebook login procedure will be handled by another developer, I was hoping I could grant additional permissions for test users without having to login the test user. Basically similar how you can use the graph explorer on your own account and give extended permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible via the Test User tool. You cannot access the API Explorer tool using a test user, which leaves logging into the app itself as your only option.

Answer (score 7):

If what you want is to create some test access tokens for specific scopes and test different api functions with them, try this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

There click the "Get Access Token" button, select any specific scope you want.

Sometimes you may see some checkboxes checked and you can't disable them by clicking. Then use the "Clear" button at the bottom.

Comment: This does not work for test users.  Only your own personal facebook account.

Comment: Correct. I get an error when attempting to generate the token as a test user "Users not logged into their personal account cannot access developers.facebook.com Warning To continue, please log out and sign in with your personal account."

Comment: Where do I see the test user password? I created a test user account, but not seeing the password.